# Is there a maximum or minimum top absolute position for SVG images in IE

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, css-position

I'm using absolute positioning to move a **VERY** large `SVG img` around inside another `div` element. I've set up a jsFiddle as a demo:

[http://jsfiddle.net/wEBnE/6](http://jsfiddle.net/wEBnE/6/)

This works fine in all browsers except (you guessed it) IE. Click the button in the jsFiddle a few times. It increases the top position 3 times until it goes beyond -84245px - then the image stops moving. The css property still increases, but the visible element remains in the same position.

As far as I can tell, this only happens with an `img` tag. I have other `div` elements that work fine like this.

Am I correct in thinking it must be some sort of built-in IE maximum setting and is there a way to override this behaviour?

Thanks

Comment: It's not the value of the top, but rather the height. Add 800px margin top, and you'll see that the image goes to the same point, but with a much lower `top` value

Comment: @SmokeyPHP - I'm not sure I follow. Can you alter the jsFiddle? Thanks for the help

Comment: Sure, see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wEBnE/7/) - the image stops at the same point, but the top value is `-85045`

Comment: So do you mean that the maximum value of the element that IE applies is actually that of the height property? Ah, but that put's me no further to a solution then?

Comment: Not the height property, but how high up the page - basically it's not specifically the `top` property with a limit, it seems to just not want to position the element too far up, by whatever means. Anyway - why must it be so large?? If you want a zoomed in section of it, I'd suggest creating a new smaller image.

Comment: @SmokeyPHP It's a dynamic view port of the very zoomed in position. So the user can click and drag to another position. It would be far too slow to have to dynamically build a smaller cropped version of the image every time someone moves to the next position just a few pixels along.

Comment: Build a grid of zoomed in positions, an additional row and column loaded outside the current view at any time. That way when the user moves the view it seems smooth, but takes less memory and space.